# Typo3 Installation on CentOS 7 with php7 and nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, typo3

I'm trying to install Typo3 on my CentOS server. 
I want to run it with php7 and nginx.

If i do a index.php with phpinfo it works. after i change the index of to the index from Typo3 it doesent work anymore.

```
http://baddog.me/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/typo3/sysext/install/Start/Install.php
```

my Nginx config:

```
server {
server_name baddog.me;

listen       80;
root         /var/www/typo3/htdocs;
location ~* \.(?:jpg|css|js|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|json|woff)$ {
    expires 1M;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /500.html;

location = /500 {
    return 500;
}

location /500.html {
    internal;
}

location /robots.txt {
}

location /favicon.ico {
}

location ~ \.png {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location / {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/typo3/htdocs/index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

i changed some parameters in the php.ini.

Sorry for my bad english. I hope for help :) ty

Answer (score 0):

Why do you hardcode the `index.php` as only file that is passed to `PHP`?

```
server {  
    listen *:8080;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name php7;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Check `port` (`listen`), `root` and `server_name` and adopt them as needed.

Also make sure that all files have the correct security label (`selinux`), thus run `$ restorecon -rv /var/www/html`.

Comment: Okei. I changed some things and now it works fine. My typo3 Installation is reachable.. But i get an error.

`Directory / is not writable
Path /var/www/typo3/htdocs exists, but no file underneath it can be created.`


`PHP extension zip not loaded
TYPO3 CMS uses PHP extension zip but it is not loaded in your environment. Change your environment to provide this extension.`

Comment: 1. The files and folders of your `TYPO3` installation need to be writable to the the user of the PHP process. 2. You need to change your `php.ini` configuration for `php-fpm` to include the `zip` `PHP`-extension.